Return an HTTP error response in rust tokio tungstenite
I'm trying to build a websocket server using rust tokio tungstenite.
When the user connects, I want them to specify a roomID as a request query parameter.
If this roomID parameter does not exist, I want to reject websocket connection, and send an HTTP 400 error instead.
I'm using the accept_hdr_async function to do this, however instead of an HTTP response being sent, the connection is simply closed when I return an Err.
How would I achieve something like this?
Here's my code so far:
let websockek_stream_result = tokio_tungstenite::accept_hdr_async(
    stream,
    |req, mut res| {
        let url = Url::parse(&format!("localhost:9090{}", req.uri().to_string()))
            .expect("Invalid URL");
        let params: HashMap<String, String> = url
            .query_pairs()
            .map(|(key, value)| (key.to_string(), value.to_string()))
            .collect();
        let parsed_room_id = params.get("roomID");

        if parsed_room_id.is_none() {
            // Terminate the handshake and send an HTTP 400 error
        } else {
            println!("Room ID is: {}", parsed_room_id.unwrap());
            Ok(res)
        }
    },
)
.await;

